# How can i change the size of the choose file window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

As highlighted in the image is there a way to change the size of the window in code ?
Is there a way to specify size in pixels

Comment: I don't believe so because its on the os level but maybe theres some way I haven't heard about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog that pops up is a native to the end user and not part of JavaScript itself. So there is no way that you can actually change it... at least not in JavaScript. In fact, how that dialog works is totally dependent on the persons browsers/OS combination.

You can change the look and feel of the html field relating to `<input type='file'>`but that is it. Sorry. For more information on  styling that check out the [tutorial on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html).